# Why does the javascript-dom tag disappear when I submit my question?

Tags: support, tags

I have a question [on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592645/what-is-the-difference-between-domnodeinserted-and-domnodeinsertedintodocument). Everytime I try to add the tag javascript-dom, it does not take it. I can tag it javascript, javascript-events etc but not javascript-dom. Is it a closed/private tag? or am I doing something wrong? or is it a bug?

Comment: [Looks like there's no such tag available on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags), and you don't have enough rep to create a new one.

Comment: Javascript is a better tag for your post, because all experts can see your post. Users don't follow narrow tags, they follow broader tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>[image: JavaScript synonyms]</kbd>

It's a synonym of [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). Thus, as I understand it, it gets replaced with the javascript tag. In this case, you already have the javascript tag, so the synonym just gets removed.

Comment: Thanks. Even though I have been a proud SO community member for about 7 months, I never noticed the tag-synonym section. That was kinda stupid on my part. Sorry and Thanks again